# Procedure to map all relationships between elements in a list of lists

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

I'm looking for an algorithm that can map all the relationships between all of the elements in sublists belonging to a list of length `n`.

More concretely, suppose `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` and `f` are the names of workers and that each sublist represents a 'shift' that occurred yesterday. I'd like to know, for each worker, who worked with who yesterday.

```
shifts_yesterday = [[a, b, c, d], [b, c, e, f]]
```

Goal:

```
a: b, c, d
b: a, c, d, e, f
c: a, b, d, e, f
d: a, b, c
e: b, c, f
f: b, c, e
```

Above, I can see that `a` worked with `b, c, d` yesterday; `b` worked with `a, c, d, e, f` yesterday, etc.

Time complexity is a concern here as I have a large list to process.
Though, intuitively, I suspect there is a pretty high floor on this one...

Note: I can obviously write a <strike>linear search</strike> straightforward approach with only `for` loops, but that is (a) not very clever (b) very slow.

#### Edit:

Here's (a messy) attempt:

```
shifts = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'c', 'e', 'f']]
workers = [i for s in shifts for i in s]

import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(list)

for w in workers:
    for s in shifts:
        for i in s:
            if i != w and w in s:
                if w in d.keys():
                    if i not in d[w]:
                        d[w].append(i)
                else:
                    d[w].append(i)
```

Test:

```
for k, v in collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items())).items():
    print(k, v)
```

#### Edit 2:

Times:

1. mine: `%%timeit -r 10` --> `10000 loops, best of 10: 19 µs per loop`
2. Padraic Cunningham: `%%timeit -r 10` --> `100000 loops, best of 10:
   4.89 µs per loop`
3. zvone: `%%timeit -r 10` --> `100000 loops, best of 10: 3.88 µs per
   loop`
4. pneumatics: `%%timeit -r 10` --> `10000 loops, best of 10: 33.5 µs per loop`

Comment: Are you saying a linear solution is no good? Can you add your current working implementation?

Comment: By "linear" you mean O(n)? That is the theoretical limit.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham. Added.

Comment: @zvone. Yes, I suspected that was so. Thanks. I was more referring to finding the best implementation. That is, my comment at the end was referring to whether or not a `for` loop soup in python is the fastest way to get there...i.e., my current approach.

Comment: Well, even in your own code there are a multitude of improvements you can make. You won't be getting a linear solution though.

Comment: Nesting for loops is not _linear_, it's _polynomial_.

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham. Certainly, I only wrote it on the spot to show the type of approach I could currently conceive of. It's too unreadable to be something I'd actually use.

Comment: @David. Touche. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Cool, I like the microbenchmarks! @zvone 's implementation is similar to mine, but I'm doing a bunch of rework by finding the workers individually. In my hands, it's about twice as slow, but about the same speed as your original solution. The print statements make the comparison look worse, none of the others are printing in the code that you're timing.

Comment: @pneumatics I did remove the actual `print` command when I ran it, but I grant the formatting may be forcing your solution to pay an unfair penalty. I can update it later (and I will!) when I have a moment. Feel free to edit the times, though, if you'd prefer not to wait.

Comment: Oh, it's no problem. For this question, @zvone's solution is readable, compact and fast, and since it's using the same set updating technique as I did, is essentially superior to mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
result = defaultdict(set)

for shift in shifts:
    for worker in shift:
        result[worker].update(shift)

# now, result[a] contains: a, b, c, d - so remove the a

for k, v in result.iteritems():
    v.remove(k)
```

Answer (score 2):

A simplified and more efficient version of your own code using sets to store values and *itertools.combinations* to pair up the workers:

```
shifts = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'c', 'e', 'f']]


from itertools import combinations
import collections

d = collections.defaultdict(set)
for sub in shifts:
    for a, b in combinations(sub, 2):
        d[a].add(b)
        d[b].add(a)

for k, v in sorted(d.items()):
print(k, v)
```

Which would give you:

```
('a', set(['c', 'b', 'd']))
('b', set(['a', 'c', 'e', 'd', 'f']))
('c', set(['a', 'b', 'e', 'd', 'f']))
('d', set(['a', 'c', 'b']))
('e', set(['c', 'b', 'f']))
('f', set(['c', 'b', 'e']))
```

On your small sample input:

```
In [1]: import collections

In [2]: %%timeit
   ...: shifts = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'c', 'e', 'f']]
   ...: workers = [i for s in shifts for i in s]
   ...: d = collections.defaultdict(list)
   ...: for w in workers:
   ...:     for s in shifts:
   ...:         for i in s:
   ...:             if i != w and w in s:
   ...:                 if w in d.keys():
   ...:                     if i not in d[w]:
   ...:                         d[w].append(i)
   ...:                 else:
   ...:                     d[w].append(i)
   ...: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.6 µs per loop

In [3]: from itertools import combinations

In [4]: %%timeit
   ...: shifts = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'c', 'e', 'f']]
   ...: d = collections.defaultdict(set)
   ...: for sub in shifts:
   ...:     for a, b in combinations(sub, 2):
   ...:         d[a].add(b)
   ...:         d[b].add(a)
   ...: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.55 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo-code algorithm:

```
declare two-dimensional array workers
for each shift in shifts_yesterday
    for each element x in shift
        add x to workers[x]
        for each element y != x in shift
            add y to workers[x]

for each list xs in workers
    print xs[0] + ": "
    for each element w in xs except the first
        print xs[w] + ", "
```

The time complexity is `O(n*m^2 + w*m)` where `n` is the number of shifts, `m` is the maximum number of workers in any shift and `w` is the total number of workers. If you could settle for seeing each worker once (don't display both `a: b` and `b: a`) you could shave off one `m`. That's a quadratic algorithm, I believe that's the best you can do.

Answer (score 1):

There is should be more conditions specified. For instance, if you have a total "shifts_yesterday" array size limited to 64 then you can use long type to store shift-bit for worker. then you can answer on the question via single operation :

```
a = 00000001  
b = 00000011  
d = 00000010  
f = 00000010
```

Does b work with d ?

```
((b & d) != 0) : true
```

Does a work with f ?

```
((a & f) != 0) : false
```

Comment: This is very efficient. I'd say it's the _number of workers_ that needs to be less than the _number of bits_ in the variables. You can make it work for more workers by using an array.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a set membership relationship. Let's call it `coworkers`:

```
shifts_yesterday = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'c', 'e', 'f']]

def coworkers(worker, shifts):
    coworkers = set()
    coworkers.update( *[shift for shift in shifts if worker in shift] )
    return coworkers
```

For each worker, you create a set of all the shifts that include the worker.

```
everybody = set()
everybody.update( *shifts_yesterday )

for worker in everybody:
     print("{}: {}".format(worker, coworkers(worker, shifts_yesterday)))
```

The output is

```
a: set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'd'])
c: set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd', 'f'])
b: set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd', 'f'])
e: set(['c', 'b', 'e', 'f'])
d: set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'd'])
f: set(['c', 'b', 'e', 'f'])
```